# Java Date Time discrepancy

Tags: java, spring, date, time, mocking

While writing integration test I  was expecting a hardcoded date in the response.

Basically I hardcoded `expected date value '2020-11-10T00:00:00.000-05:00'`
and ran  `new GregorianCalendar(2020, 10, 10).getTime()`

When I put and assert and run it locally it passes, however when the same code was pushed to bamboo build server the actualValue it generated was`'2020-11-10T00:00:00.000Z'` and so my test failed.

1. Why the same calendar.getTime generating two different times, is it because the server machine is configured to be on GMT?
2. Can I do something to have them the same time or any other workaround?

NOTE: Making it string or comparing dates without time is not an option here, as I am using Spring MockWebServiceServer, where in I must hardcode the responseXML and specify date, something like this in Enum.

```
 REQUESTAUTOMATESETTLEMENTWORKCASE("<aut:AutomateSettlementWorkcaseRequest xmlns:aut=\"http://www.abcd.com/abcd/workflow/services/workcase/model/AutomateSettlementWorkcase_1_0_0\">" +
          "  <aut:customerAccountId>5049903033584324</aut:customerAccountId>\n" +
          "  <aut:settlementDate>2020-11-10T00:00:00.000-05:00</aut:settlementDate>\n" +
          "  </aut:AutomateSettlementWorkcaseRequest>"),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "-5" part in your input data is throwing it off... ideally you should specify the time zone when constructing the calendar, and then set it to 5am UTC (for example). Basically, `2020-11-10T00:00:00.000-05:00` is the same instant as `2020-11-10T05:00:00.000Z`.

Now, what we don't know is whether it's important to you that you preserve the offset from UTC. If it is, you need to set an appropriate time zone in the calendar - one which has the same rules as whatever's generating your input data. If it isn't, I'd use UTC and set the time appropriately.

I would personally recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of `Calendar` and `Date` though - it's a *much* better date and time API. No 0-based months, for starters :)

Comment: I would love to use Joda Time, but its not an option for me in my workplace. Getting November is not a concern for me either (thats the date I am expecting). I am just wondering **why it produces a trailing Z** when calender.getTime() runs on build server but -05:00 in my local machine. I also tried setting the timezone to UTC, but it still has trailing Z in server.         `GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2020, 10, 10);
        TimeZone tz=TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
        cal.setTimeZone(tz);`

Comment: @Himalay: The trailing Z indicates UTC. You should work out what time zone you *want* to be using, and set it explicitly. Will edit about the November part - I misread your test case.

Comment: As you can see in my comment above, I am explicitly setting the TimeZone to UTC, but it does NOT produce a trailing Z in my local machine, but only in the server? Thanks for your response

Comment: @Himalay: Well, you haven't given any indication of how you're printing the value, for one thing. A short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem would be useful. At the moment we've just got bits and pieces of information.

Comment: While composing the question with all source, I realized that timezone was getting reset somewhere else, I am fine now. Thanks for your patience :)